# What to do with questions already answered on the network?

Tags: discussion

Looking into unanswered questions section, I stumbled upon a few that have already been answered on other sites of the StackExchange network. There is one answered on Skeptics.SE [In Japan, the official average body temperature is 36.0 °C. Why so different from that of Europe?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11039/in-japan-mean-human-body-is-36-0-%C2%B0c-why-so-different-from-europe) and there is this one answered on CogSci.SE [Does our brain really "flip" images perceived by our eyes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/does-our-brain-really-flip-images-perceived-by-our-eyes). The links to answers are posted as comments.

What should we do with these questions?

- answer them? Duplicate questions/answers across different SE sites?
- flag for closing? We're still in beta, and we haven't reach the 15 questions per day threshold...
- leave them as they are? We didn't reach the answer ratio threshold either...

**Update:** Here's another one:

- https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/biological-molecular-basis-of-nutritional-need-differences-between-blood-types

Comment: This is ultimately up to this community, but I would say it's perfectly reasonable to provide a summary of the answer from the other site (if it is sufficiently scientifically rigorous) and link to it.

Comment: I suggest that the answer from the other site can be linked + quoted verbatim and posted as community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do similar to what WYSIWYG suggested, and quote the parts you want verbatim, of course linking it back to the source. I would also add my own touches, going over details more carefully, add my own section if the other answer missed something, etc.

It is similar to using information from non-related sites. It's okay to quote them, but don't forget to reveal your sources. Always give credit where credit is due.